# Файл xls не открывается

Tags: header, php, xls, excel

Есть файл формате xls, с регенерирован средствами php. 
Он открывается через программы норм (микрософт офис), а вот через гугл таблицу (браузере) пишет ошибку (не известная, просто ошибка в открытии).
Чего в этом файле не хватает?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="Table1">
<Table>
<Column ss:Index="1" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="110"/>
<Row>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Фамилия покупателя,номер заказа</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Категория</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Бренд</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Номер модели</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Размер</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Цвет</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Кол-во штук</Data></Cell>
</Row>

<Row>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> Дроздова, #806</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Платье</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PRIO</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">117280</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">44</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Черный и бежевый крем</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Возможно гугл просто не поддерживает такой нестандартный формат файла, это не xls а xml файл (просто excel такой лайф-хак хавает, для упрощения этот метод всюду советуют, но редко говорят о последствиях). Нормальный xls файл должен иметь bof заголовок (для версий 1-4) (либа вот например http://gist.github.com/ihumanable/929039) либо biff8 заголовок (для 8 версии, сигнатура D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1) последнее лучше, т к в новом офисе версия 1-4 может даже не открыться. Поищите другую либу для генерации xls. Ещё можно использовать xlsx файл (тоже искать либу).